# Finding the value Submit button onclick

Tags: jquery

I have two button in my form

```
 <input type="submit" name="_finish" id="_finish" value="Submit" class="butn" />

 <input type="submit" name="_cancel" value="Close" class="butn" style="width:60px;"/>
```

I am trying to find which button is clicked.Searching on google I got jquery code like this

```
var val = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val();
```

But alerting this value shows that this is undefined.How can I fulfil my goal.Any know help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the click handle as the submit event does not give info on which button was clicked

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    alert(this.value);
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UGt22/)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("input[type='submit']").submit(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/z5RSj/)

try this:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Close") alert("close clicked");
    if ($(this).val() == "Submit") alert("Submit clicked");    
});
```